# Java Basic Gui Example

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm new to GUIS's in Java and I am trying to create a GUI like the image I have attached, but with multiple JLabels and JTextFields. I would like to have the button positioned in the center at the bottom of the screen.

How do I go about doing this ? Please disregard the black lines as I couldn't find a better image.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this.  For me, the easiest way is to use `GridBagLayout`, it's the most flexible of all the built in layout managers, it is also one of the most complicated :P

One thing that a lot of people get caught up on, is trying to layout there components on a single container.  This can be done, but takes a lot of time and tweaking to get just right.

A better approach (IMHO) is to use multiple, child containers.

This allows you to break down the layout requirements to there individual needs and worry about the relationship between these containers as a separate issue.

For example, in you question, you have a requirement that the word and text field be aligned together, but that they be anchored to the north position of the container and the button should be to the south, but centered between the label and the field.

Worry about how to layout the label and field first, then worry about the relationship between these button and the field/label second...

[image]

```
public class TestLayout08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout08();
    }

    public TestLayout08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new LayoutPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    protected  class LayoutPane extends JPanel {

        public LayoutPane() {
            JButton button = new JButton("Find Word");
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Word:");
            JTextField field = new JTextField(12);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            fieldPane.add(label, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            fieldPane.add(field, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(fieldPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            add(button, gbc);    
        }        
    }
}
```

Take a look at;

- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: +1 Although GridBagLayout is not the easiest to start with since it has so many possibilities. Also, but that just for expert usage, it is usually better not to set gridx and gridy with absolute values, but rather use RELATIVE and REMAINDER which allows easier further updates, but that's just nitpicking. And I agree to say that sometimes... it' just plain simpler to do so. ;)

Comment: I agree, `GridBagLayout` is a massive leap, but fits the requirements.  Normally I would seed the gridx/gridy values and offset related elements from there and gridwidth and height values will depend on the requirements.  If needed to add more components to this layout, a RELATIVE or REMAINDER may not be suitable, but that's just nick picking ;) - Good advice none the less

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options;

- Use a GUI Builder from your favorite IDE, such as NetBeans and Eclipse
- Learn how use the Swing API. In particular, you will need to learn how to use LayoutManagers. In this particular example, you might want to use a combination of BorderLayout, GridLayout or GridBagLayout, and FlowLayout.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather use Eclipse, there is a plugin called WindowsBuilder Pro, you can actually just install the plugin right in Eclipse.
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

Comment: IMHO, I think it is a very bad idea to suggest form designers to people who don't have, at least, a rudimentary understanding of layout managers.  This is only going to cause more issues in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Try using Netbeans. You can drag and drop all these features and then you just need to program the code for the functions of the buttons. The classes get created for you too.

Alternatively, I'd start from the beginning, learn how to build it from scratch, considering it's a very basic GUI.

http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php

Comment: IMHO, I think it is a very bad idea to suggest form designers to people who don't have, at least, a rudimentary understanding of layout managers.  This is only going to cause more issues in the long run

Comment: I agree with you, but I gave them what they wanted to the best of my ability at the time. I did recommend learning themselves too though and gave them a link to do so.

Comment: It's just my personally opinion. I've rejected a number of candidates recently for not being able to do basic things, like use layout managers or `AbstractTableModel` :P - Personally, I use form editors all the time, but they are a tool that I can use to apply my knowledge and experience ;)

Comment: *"I agree with you, but I gave them.."* ..clear instructions on how to shoot their own feet!